# Keep Asp.Net site in IIS warm

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have an internal asp.net site in IIS 7.5 on 2008R2. The first load in the morning is sloow, more than 40 seconds.

Here is what I have done without success

Installed Application Initialization Module for IIS 7.5

Following setup for the application pool

- Process Model: Idle Time-out = 0
- Recycling: Regular Time Interval = 0
- AutoStart = True
- StartMode = AlwaysRunning

Setup for the site

- PreloadEnabled = True
- Setup to load the root

I then did a manual app pool recycle and waited for things to settle down and hit the site. Took 4 seconds, much better, but not quite there.

It feels wrong and seems like it shouldn't be necessary. But I added some warmup code in the site itself, that hits the database and gets a few pages from itself using HttpClient. This code is run on the first request (preload) and every 15 minute using a timer.

After a manual recycle, the first load is fast as it should be. So warmup code is good, I guess.

But checking the site the next morning in Chrome, first load took 40 seconds again :-(.

I browsed to the default page, which is also get'd by the warmup code. I can see from the log that the warmup code has run fine all night and just a few minutes before browsing the site.

I think I have used all the tricks, so where do I go from here?

My ideas, move the warmup code out of the site and start it by task scheduler, perhaps even from another computer?

Using HttpClient to get a few pages, isn't the same as using a real browser. Perhaps using something like wget in a script would be better.

Comment: Have you added "Application Initialization" in IIS? http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/02/Use-IIS-Application-Initialization-for-keeping-ASPNET-Apps-alive

Comment: It's the first thing I list of things I have done

Comment: Sorry mate, missed it... :/